# Is it necessary to configure Excel service application and secure store to view excel reports in SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, excel, excel-services, secure-store

We are using SharePoint 2013. Now we need to add some excel sheets and excel reports onto the SharePoint page. So we have seen that there is a Excel viewer webpart.

I was wondering whether it is necessary to configure Excel service application and secure store to view excel sheets and reports in SharePoint?

If not, then what is the purpose of configuring Excel service application and secure store?